# como aumentar o limite de ifelse no R?

Tags: r, if

Preciso calcular os anos de estudo a partir do questionário da pnad.

Fiz uma programação parecida com esta abaixo, mas tenho muitos ifelse dentro do outro (121 para ser exato), pois tenho uma cadeia de perguntas maior, mas o R não calcula além de 50 linhas de ifelse.

```
pnad2015$agua<-ifelse(v0211==1 & v0212==2, 0,
               ifelse (v0211==1 & v0212==4, 1,
               ifelse (v0211==1 & v0212==6, 1,
               ifelse (v0211==3 & v0213==1, 0,
               ifelse (v0211==3 & v0213==3, 1, NA)))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma possível forma é usar o `case_when` do `dplyr`. Fiz alguns testes e não encontrei a limitação de muitos casos como o `ifelse` possui. No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
case_when(
  v0211==1 & v0212==2 ~ 0,
  v0211==1 & v0212==4 ~ 1,
  v0211==1 & v0212==6 ~ 1,
  v0211==3 & v0213==1 ~ 0,
  v0211==3 & v0213==3 ~ 1,
  TRUE ~ as.numeric(NA)
)
```

Veja que cada caso é definido da forma `condicao ~ resultado se verdadeiro` e separado por vírgulas. As condições são avaliadas sequencialmente, assim como o `ifelse`. A última condição `TRUE ~ NA`, indica que o valor `NA` será incluido caso nenhuma das aneteriores seja correspondida. Para ter a função `case_when`, carregue o pacote com `library(dplyr)`.

**Note que**: o limite de chamadas não é relacionado ao `ifelse` e sim ao R. O `R` limita o número de funções que podem ser chamadas uma dentro da outra (chamado de *parse context*). Veja este exemplo:

```
f <- function(x) return(1)

f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f())))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
Error: contextstack overflow at line 1
```

O limite do R é definido a 50 chamadas. E é definido [nesta linha](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/c48b62e3b4dd43d939e21f4af87e877151f1840b/src/main/gram.y#L1158) do código fonte do R. Ou seja, para alterar este limite você precisa mudar o código fonte do R. Segue uma [referência no stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25063770/3297472)

Comment: Obrigado.
agora apareceu este erro 
´Error: RHS of case 123 (NA) has type 'logical' not 'double'`

Comment: Editei a resposta. Adicione: as.numeric(NA) na última condição. A `case_when` não deixa tipos diferentes aparecerem no mesmo vetor.

Comment: Funcionou 
Obrigado